# Where do I find the "toggle CallerID" function in the iOS headers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, header, theos, cydia-substrate

I'm currently developing a mobile substrate tweak for jailbroken iOS Devices but I'm stuck at finding a specific function in the iOS headers!
I'm searching for the function that toggles the "send caller ID" option...
Does anyone know where to find it or does anyone know a method to find keywords in that pile of headers?

-cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TUCallCenter.h

`- (void)handleCallerIDChanged:(id)arg1;`